# Displaying content of div from the posts to the homepage on WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have this div in all my posts on WordPress:

```
[div class="price"] $123 [/div]
```

I would like to display the price within these divs on the homepage, just beside the post titles. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is a shortcode that you are using in your wordpress theme. Direct you can't Use this beside your post title. You need to do some programming tricks.

Alternate option is apply some css that will do the trick.

```
[div class="price alternate_opt"] $123 [/div]
```

**NOTE:**
I am not sure but mightbe `class="price alternate_opt"` would generate a new class `alternate_opt`, then apply some css on this class.

Comment: Exactly! I was wondering if this is possible with php or jquery. Just need to fetch the div from the posts and display it on the homepage. But how?